# Using table-valued function in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to execute the following update statement:

```
Update belege2  
Set Preis_Einh = x.Preis, Aktion=x.Aktion, PreisHerk = x.PreisHerk 
FROM dbo.GetPreis(belege2.prodkey, belege2.Anzahl) x
where belege2.Beleg_Nr = 13599
```

SQL Server displays the following errors:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "belege2.prodkey" could not be bound.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "belege2.Anzahl" could not be bound.
```

Is this not supported? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

did u try this with alias..

```
Update b  
Set b.Preis_Einh = x.Preis, b.Aktion=x.Aktion, b.PreisHerk = x.PreisHerk 
FROM belege2 b cross apply dbo.GetPreis(b.prodkey, b.Anzahl) x 
where b.Beleg_Nr = 13599
```

used cross apply