# Replace SQL User defined Function with Set operation to Update

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, sqlperformance

I have a table say, **TestTable** which has columns StartDate, 1stDeliveryDate, DeliveryFrequency, HolidayCalenderId(which links to other table calender).
Now i have to add a column FinalDeliveryDate which needs some calulation using the other fields mentioned above.I have managed to write a **Function** which does the calculations and updates the field. The final query to update looks something like,

```
Update  TestTable 
    Set FinalDeliveryDate = dbo.GetCalculatedFinalDeliveryDate(StartDate, 1stDeliveryDate, HolidayCalenderId)
WHere dbo.GetCalculatedFinalDeliveryDate(StartDate, 1stDeliveryDate, HolidayCalenderId) >= GETDATE
```

This example above is just to explain the scenario how the function is used. Now the size of **TestTable** is increasing rapidly as the business is growing. I am worried about **performance** as the query needs to run quite frequently and on all the rows in the test table. Just to clarify, I am a developer and not a DBA, but after researching about functions, I know its best to avoid them in Select and Where clause. If possible can someone point me in the right direction for how to remove this function and do a set operation to update the rows.. I am not able to think of any other way to **replace** this fucntion..

Comment: You might want to look at using a table valued function with cross apply.  Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253866/using-table-valued-function-in-update-statement

Comment: Here is an article, that may help you. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm

Comment: @David and Pavan- Thanks for the useful links with examples. I will rewrite the query and will test the results.

Comment: You could also try looking into calculated fields.

Comment: @David and Pavan - I have modified the query to use the cross-apply and tested. For the current scenario it improves the performance a bit by reducing the number of reads. But still it uses a function which is applied on all the rows in the left of Cross Apply. Not major improvement but every millisecond/second counts :)..

Comment: @Dub- I didn't understand what you meant ..

Comment: @Nagahornbill what I meant was computed columns, sorry for the confusion. See more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx